# React radio button with default check behaving weirdly

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to build a 3way radio button.I used this [codepen](https://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/grzqMz) which is behaving as expected in the codepen. But when i put it in my [react code](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-field-4v8fs?file=/src/App.js) it doesnt behave as expected. What happens is, when I press on left most radio(cross) and then the right most radio(tick), it first checks the middle radio then goes to the cross radio which is not the expected behaviour. It should've directly checked the right most radio as in the original non react codepen. However when I remove checked attribute from the middle radio button it works as expected ,which isn't something i want to do as i need checked attribute to show a default check.

```
 <div class="tw-toggle">
  <input type="radio" name="toggle" value="false" />
  <label class="toggle toggle-yes">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
  </label>
  <input checked type="radio" name="toggle" value="-1" />
  <label class="toggle toggle-yes">
    <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" name="toggle" value="true" />
  <label class="toggle toggle-yes">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
  </label>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: (part) of your issue is you have a `checked` property on the middle element. FWIW what's "good" in HTML isn't necessarily the appropriate path to take in React. You should manage the states of the inputs yourself via state.

Comment: I see you've updated your codesandbox to use the `defaultChecked` prop for the "middle" input. Is there still an issue? Or can this post be deleted?

Comment: yes it wast solved after i used defaultChecked.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below react code link? Hope it will work for you. We have changed the position of `span` and add it into the individual `label` tag and also change style according to that.

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-borg-e44qz

Answer (score 0):

Using defaultChecked instead of checked solved the problem or what you can do is add checked(with boolean) to all three input radio.Thank u evereyone